# Too many "insert" queries to the "cache_views" table.

Tags: 7, database, performance

I have a bad performance in my website.

Checking the database queries I see that there are too many "insert" queries to the "cache_views" table.

How can I start to trace this problem?

Comment: Look at the caching on your views, turn off what you don't need to cache any more. If you still need to cache everything, get better hardware to serve your site from

Comment: @Clive I have turned off all views cache in my site. These queries happens when I save the "manage display" page for a given content type like: 'www.example.com/en/admin/structure/types/manage/page/display?destination=node/92'

Comment: Why exactly do you consider there is too many of them?

Comment: Yep that's right - changing fields mandates a cache flush, flushing the cache means it needs to rebuilt. Your destination is node/92, which presumably has Views on it, so the cache for those Views is rebuilt as soon as the redirect happens. That's as far as you're going to get 'tracing', I think. Don't know that you have any options to improve that without changing Views code or getting a better server

Comment: @Mołot The site is running very slow. My server provider gave that information. They told me that The bad performance is due to this behavior.

Comment: @chefnelone it still depends on your views and if you really really need them all to be cached if they are so mutable. Also, if you do, why are you on hosting without memcached?

Comment: @Mołot memcached would help in this situation? I have xcache in my server.

Comment: @chefnelone anything to keep cache in RAM would get rid of cache inserts to DB, simple as that. [Memcached](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) is, in my experience, most stable solution for Drupal. I tried [Cache Router](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacherouter) - supports xcache - without any major issues, don't remember why dedicated memcache module felt better for me. If you would ask about circumventing problem (instead of tracing it), this would be my answer.

Comment: @Mołot Cache Router is for D6, something similar for D7?

Comment: @chefnelone Oh. Well, that explains it, I was using dedicated memcache module since late 6.x days... Don't know about solution for 7 :(

Comment: @chefnelone What where the details that the server provider gave you? I've found the core db cache implementation to be severely lacking, not using it usually fixes all database issues for me.

Comment: @mikeytown2 My server provider told me that 29 queries to the "cache_views" was the reason of the bad performance. Can you tell me how did you disabled the core db cache?

Comment: @chefnelone 29 queries to a cache table usually doesn't cause bad performance unless the table had some sort of lock. Did they provide any technical details on what happened? 29 queries doesn't say a lot.